# Not able to launch app in iOS simulator in vscode

Tags: ios, visual-studio-code

I am new to vscode, I tried running my code in iOS simulator but its not showing the simulator in the first place. 
the options i get are

*view android emulators*

*view iOS simulators*

But when I click on *view iOS simulators* I get a pop up saying

" ***Something went wrong fetching you iOS simulators! Make sure you have Xcode installed. Try running this command in your terminal: instruments -s devices*** "

Answer (score 5):

You may need to run this command, when VSCode tries access the simulator there may be error which says

> Cannot find "xcodebuild". Xcode 11.0.0 or greater is required to
> develop for iOS. Encountered error while building for device.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```